# Is it pythonic: naming lambdas

Tags: python, lambda

I'm beginning to appreciate the value of lambda expressions in python, particularly when it comes to functional programming, `map`, [functions returning functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16509/1533474), etc. However, I've also been naming lambdas within functions because:

- I need the same functionality several times and don't want to repeat code.
- The functionality is specific to the function in which it appears; its not needed elsewhere.

When I encounter a situation that meets the above criteria, I've been writing a named lambda expression in order to DRY and narrowly scope functionality. For example, I am writing a function that operates on some `numpy` arrays, and I need to do some moderately tedious indexing of all the arrays passed to the function (which can easily fit on a single line). I've written a named lambda expression to do the indexing instead of writing a whole other function or copy/pasting the indexing several times throughout the function definition.

```
def fcn_operating_on_arrays(array0, array1):
    indexer = lambda a0, a1, idx: a0[idx] + a1[idx]
    
    # codecodecode
    
    indexed = indexer(array0, array1, indices)
    
    # codecodecode in which other arrays are created and require `indexer`
    
    return the_answer
```

Is this an abuse of python's lambdas? Should I just suck it up and define a separate function?

### Edits

Probably worth linking [function inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831680/function-inside-function).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is not Pythonic and [PEP8 discourages it](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that
>   binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier.
>
> Yes:
>
> ```
> def f(x): return 2*x
> ```
>
> No:
>
> ```
> f = lambda x: 2*x
> ```
>
> The first form means that the name of the resulting function object is
>   specifically `'f'` instead of the generic `'<lambda>'`. This is more
>   useful for tracebacks and string representations in general. The use
>   of the assignment statement eliminates the sole benefit a lambda
>   expression can offer over an explicit def statement (i.e. that it can
>   be embedded inside a larger expression)

A rule of thumb for this is to think on its [definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda): lambdas expressions are anonymous functions. If you name it, it isn't anonymous anymore. :)

Answer (score 9):

> I've written a named lambda expression to do the indexing instead of writing a whole other function

Well, you *are* writing a whole other function. You're just writing it with a lambda expression.

Why not use `def`? You get nicer stack traces and more syntactical flexibility, and you don't lose anything. It's not like `def` can't occur inside another function:

```
def fcn_operating_on_arrays(array0, array1):
    def indexer(a0, a1, idx):
        return a0[idx] + a1[idx]
    ...
```

Comment: How pythonic is `def` within another function? Whenever I've seen someone do that they were abusing it.

Comment: @joshua.r.smith: Putting a `def` inside another function is perfectly fine. People do it all the time for decorators or other cases when they want a closure. I personally prefer to avoid it when the inner function doesn't use any closure variables, since it's convenient to be able to access the function for testing or interactive use.