# How to make the inverse of a linear function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm trying to work with linear functions for data conversion (like meters to feet).

I'm trying to find a way to build a lambda function that returns the inverse function and another lambda function that return the composition of those functions

```
inches_to_meters=lambda x:x*0.0254
inches_to_feets=lambda x:x*(1/12)
miles_to_feets=lambda x:x*5280
composition=lambda x,y,z: lambda x,y: x(y(z))
opposite=lambda x: 1/x
meters_to_inches=opposite(inches_to_meters)
miles_to_inches = composition(feets_to_inches, miles_to_feets)
print(meters_to_inches(10))
```

how can I make the opposite function (`F^-1(x)`)?

(For example: `y=x/12`, then `12*y=x`, the opposite is: `12*x=y`).

Comment: If you know `x` is linear you can define `lambda y: y/x(1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it is better to **use the `def ...` statement rather than `lambda` to define named functions**. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381556/is-it-pythonic-naming-lambdas) SO question and its answers for more details. But if I understand correctly what you want to achieve, it might be better to define the linear function as a class (see below).

---

The inverse of the [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function):

[image: linear function]

is given by:

[image: inverse of linear function]

and depends on both the slope `a` and the intercept `b`. An important consequence of this is that **you need to know both `a` and `b` to define its inverse in a functional form**.

In python you can achieve this for example if you **define a class of linear functions and the inverse as one of its methods**:

```
class f_lin:
    def __init__(self, a, b=0):
        self.a = float(a)
        self.b = b

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.a * x + self.b

    def inv(self, y):
        return (y - self.b) / self.a
```

Now you can define:

```
inches_to_meters = f_lin(0.0254)
```

and use it like so:

```
inches_to_meters(10)
Out[38]: 0.254
inches_to_meters.inv(0.254)
Out[39]: 10.0
inches_to_meters.inv(inches_to_meters(10))
Out[40]: 10.0
```

---

Alternatively you could also **create a new object for the inverse, as the inverse of a linear function is still a linear function**:

```
class f_lin:
    def __init__(self, a, b=0):
        self.a = float(a)
        self.b = b

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.a * x + self.b

    def get_inverse(self):
        return self.__class__(1/self.a, - self.b/self.a)
```

Then you can define the inverse function like so:

```
inches_to_meters = f_lin(0.0254)
meters_to_inches = inches_to_meters.get_inverse()
```

Now you have both the linear function and its inverse as objects:

```
inches_to_meters(10)
Out[43]: 0.254
meters_to_inches(0.254)
Out[44]: 10.0
inches_to_meters(meters_to_inches(10))
Out[45]: 10.0
```

---

Those are just 2 ways of doing, both not using `lambda` as requested. However **I would advise against doing such things with `lambda`**.

Answer (score 0):

```
opposite = lambda f : (lambda x: x*x*1/f(x))
```

work perfect

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer that `lambda` is not recommended due to the pool tracebacks and string representations of `lambda` expression in general.

However in my opinion, the `lambda` could still be useful in this case of linear function inverse. However if the functions gets complicated, i'd still prefer `def` statement in general.

Anyway, Below is the `lambda` implementation:

```
a = 2
b = 3 
func = lambda x: a*x+b
inverse = lambda f: (lambda y: (y-b) / a)
func_inv = inverse(func)

# test
for x in range(10):
    y = func(x)
    x1 = func_inv(y)
    print('For y=f(x)={}x+{} when x={},'.format(a, b, x), 'y={}'.format(y))
    print("inverse function of y={} is {}\n".format(y, x1))
    assert x == x1
```

Output:

```
For y=f(x)=2x+3 when x=0, y=3
inverse function of y=3 is 0.0

For y=f(x)=2x+3 when x=1, y=5
inverse function of y=5 is 1.0

For y=f(x)=2x+3 when x=2, y=7
inverse function of y=7 is 2.0

For y=f(x)=2x+3 when x=3, y=9
inverse function of y=9 is 3.0

For y=f(x)=2x+3 when x=4, y=11
inverse function of y=11 is 4.0

For y=f(x)=2x+3 when x=5, y=13
inverse function of y=13 is 5.0

For y=f(x)=2x+3 when x=6, y=15
inverse function of y=15 is 6.0

For y=f(x)=2x+3 when x=7, y=17
inverse function of y=17 is 7.0

For y=f(x)=2x+3 when x=8, y=19
inverse function of y=19 is 8.0

For y=f(x)=2x+3 when x=9, y=21
inverse function of y=21 is 9.0
```