# Is there a inner function that can calculate x=f-1 (y) when I know y=f(x)

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example, I define a function like that:

```
def trapezoid(x, a, b, c, d):
    if x <= a:
        return 0
    if a < x <= b:
        return (x - a)/(b - a)
    if b < x <= c:
        return 1
    if c < x <= d:
        return (d - x)/(d - c)
    if d < x:
    return 0
```

Now I can calculate the value of y according to input x, but if I know the value of y,how can I calculate x directly? Is there some way in numpy or other library?

for example:

```
print(trapezoid(12, 10, 30, 50, 90))
```

0.1

but if I know the result= 0.1, how to calculate the input x(12)? I know there may be a large number of x can get same y, but if I want to know the field of x?

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` constants relative to `x` and `y`?

Comment: The problem is that your function is not bijective: y=0, for example, has no unique solution. As for the linear parts, consider this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48126944/1622937

Comment: If you can frame the function as an equation, then you might be able to use [`pynverse`](https://pypi.org/project/pynverse/)

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy  a,b,c,d just some constant like 1,2,3,4 as parameter

Comment: What is `y`?  It isn't mentioned in the code

Comment: @jojo Actually, I want to calculate all possible value of x when I know the value of y

Comment: @SimonCrane the return result is y

Comment: With just an arbitrary black-box function `f`, this is impossible. The more you know about `f`, the more possible it is.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks again, if I only want to know the f in example, is there some good method?

Comment: From y to x would depend on a,b,c,d. You need to specify or consider a,b,c,d.