# Error : TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x

For below code i am getting `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'`

```
square = lambda x : x*x
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
square_nums = []
for x in nums:
    square(nums)
    square_nums.append(x)
print (square_nums)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Use `square(x) `

Comment: Expected Output : Square of numbers in list **nums**. I have used **square(x)** but it does provides expected output

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify (and fix the indenting while you're there). Check out [ask] for more advice.

Comment: @abhilb I rolled back your edit since it fundamentally changed the code. Yes, it's probably how OP intended it, but you can't tell for sure. For example is the `print` line supposed to be indented? Your edit also introduced a few other problems, which I can explain if you like.

Comment: Sure do, my code was not indented properly in the post here but it wasnt an indentation issue with me. But Appreciate your help

Comment: BTW, [it's bad practice to name a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38381556/4518341). Use a `def` instead: `def square(x): return x * x`. Also IMO writing `x ** 2` is simpler.

Comment: @ManojGupta  Indentation in python is significant.  If you are asking a question, you have the obligation to make sure your code is readable and runnable for other.

Comment: @AdrianShum, Thanks, I ll make sure next time i properly post my code for review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong code :

> **square(nums)** should be **square(x)** because you want to square x

and simplify your code into :

```
square = lambda x : x*x
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
square_nums = [square(x) for x in nums]
print (square_nums)
```

Result:

> [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]

Note from @wjandrea:

it's bad practice to name a lambda.

Use a def instead: `def square(x): return x * x`. 
Also IMO writing `x ** 2` is simpler. (x to the power of 2)

Final result:

```
def square(x): return x**2
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
square_nums = [square(x) for x in nums]
print (square_nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
square_nums = [x*x for x in nums]
print(square_nums)

[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Comment: Need to use **Lambda** function to solve it

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use lambda, it makes more sense to use `map` instead.  It is just weird to create a lambda but assign a name to it, as lambda is supposed to be an anonymous block of code.

```py
nums = [1, 2, 3]
square_nums = list( map(lambda x: x*x, nums) )
# square_nums contains [1, 4, 9]
```