# How can I convert my function output in List?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to use Fibonacci series and get Cubes of the series. My Fibonacci function is giving an output but I want that output to be in a List form. 
Following is my code

```
cube = lambda x : x ** 3
def fibonacci(n): 
    a = 0
    b = 1
    count = 0
    if n < 0: 
        print("Incorrect input") 
    elif n == 0: 
        return a 
    elif n == 1: 
        return b 
    else: 
        while count < n: 
            print(a)
            c = a + b 
            a = b 
            b = c 
            count += 1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input())
    print(list(map(cube,fibonacci(n))))
```

I am getting the following output with error:

```
6
0
1
1
2
3
5

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-58624b7f0dd2> in <module>
      1 if __name__ == "__main__":
      2     n = int(input())
----> 3     print(list(map(cube,fibonacci(n))))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

---

I am very new to coding. Please help!

Comment: `map` takes a function and an iterable as parameters, the error is with your fibonacci function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd your Fibonacci function to return a list, change it as follows:

```
def fibonacci(n): 
    a = 0
    b = 1
    count = 0
    res = []
    if n < 0: 
        print("Incorrect input") 
    elif n == 0: 
        return [a] 
    elif n == 1: 
        return [b] 
    else: 
        while count < n: 
            res.append(a)
            c = a + b 
            a = b 
            b = c 
            count += 1
        return res
```

You can then run:

```
n = 5
print(list(map(cube,fibonacci(n))))
```

Which results in:

```
[0, 1, 1, 8, 27]
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could build a `list` right away as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62016663/5218354), this task can be solved more efficiently using [generators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1756096/5218354).
The idea is that with the generator you do the computation when actually required and you do not (need to) store potentially large intermediate objects.

Also, note [how swapping is done in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14836228/5218354) and [why `name = lambda ...` is an anti-pattern in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38381556/5218354).

```py
def fibonacci(n): 
    a = 0
    b = 1
    count = 0
    if n < 0: 
        print("Incorrect input")
        return
    elif n == 0: 
        yield a 
    elif n == 1: 
        yield b 
    else: 
        while count < n: 
            yield a
            a, b = b, a + b 
            count += 1


def cube(x):
    return x ** 3


n = 8
print(list(fibonacci(n)))
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
print(list(map(cube, fibonacci(n))))
# [0, 1, 1, 8, 27, 125, 512, 2197]
```

Comment: Thank you @norok2. Be safe. Cheers