# object of type 'filter' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, area, montecarlo

i'm trying to use the simulation of monte carlo in order to calculate the area under the curve  (python 3.8)
[image]

**in order to get this plot eventually**
[image]

i tried this code

```
import random, math

NUM_POINTS = 10000

# Function for which we want to find area from (x=0 to 10).
f = lambda x: 5 * math.sin(6 * x) + 3 * math.sin(2 * x) + 7

# Sample rectangle will be (x,y) such that 0 <= x <= 10 and 0 <= y <= 14.
rect_width = 10
rect_height = 14

# Funcitions to generate samples for x and y respectively.
rand_x = lambda: random.uniform(0, rect_width)
rand_y = lambda: random.uniform(0, rect_height)

# Generate random sample points.
points = [(rand_x(), rand_y()) for i in range(NUM_POINTS)]

# Find points under our function
points_under = filter(lambda point: point[1] <= f(point[0]), points)

# Area = area of domain rectangle * num_points_under/num_points_total
area = rect_width * rect_height * len(points_under)*1.0/len(points)
print ("Estimate of area under the curve:", area)
```

i'm having this error :

> object of type 'filter' has no len()

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: BTW, the graphs and most of your code are totally irrelevant to the problem. In the future, please provide a [mre]. As well, I just googled the error message and that question was the top result. In the future, please try researching for yourself. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Also BTW, [named lambdas are bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381663/4518341). Just use a `def` instead.

Comment: This is one of the major gotchas in switching from Python2 to Python3.  `filter` returns an iterator rather than a list.    I don't know why the Python gods decided that `sum(iterator)` does the obvious right thing while `len(iterator)` gives an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys , since it is a 2.X python code and i'm using a 3.X version of python , so this tool was helpful in order to convert my code :
https://www.pythonconverter.com/