# Python: understanding lambda operations in a function

Tags: python, function, lambda

Suppose I have a function designed to find the largest `Y` value in a list of dictionaries.

```
s1 = [
    {'x':10, 'y':8.04},
    {'x':8, 'y':6.95},
    {'x':13, 'y':7.58},
    {'x':9, 'y':8.81},
    {'x':11, 'y':8.33},
    {'x':14, 'y':9.96},
    {'x':6, 'y':7.24},
    {'x':4, 'y':4.26},
    {'x':12, 'y':10.84},
    {'x':7, 'y':4.82},
    {'x':5, 'y':5.68},
    ]

def range_y(list_of_dicts):
    y = lambda dict: dict['y']
    return y(min(list_of_dicts, key=y)), y(max(list_of_dicts, key=y))

range_y(s1)
```

This works and gives the intended result.

What I don't understand is the `y` before the `(min(list_of_dicts, key=y)`. I know I can find the `min` and `max` with `min(list_of_dicts, key=lambda d: d['y'])['y']` where the `y` parameter goes at the end (obviously swapping `min` for `max`).

Can someone explain to me what is happening in `y(min(list_of_dicts, key=y))` with the `y` and the parenthetical?

Comment: Well, the `lambda` defines a function. And that function is assigned to `y`. So `y` points to the function defined by the `lambda`. It's as if you did `def y(dict): return dict['y']`.

Comment: Note that using `dict` as a variable shadows the `dict` builtin. It's not recommended. If you really can't think of a better name for that variable, consider using `dict_`.

Answer (score 1):

`y` is a function, where the function is defined by the `lambda` statement. The function accepts a dictionary as an argument, and returns the value at key `'y'` in the dictionary.

`min(list_of_dicts, key=y)` returns the dictionary from the list with the smallest value under key `'y'`

so putting it together, you get the value at key `'y'` in the dictionary from the list with the smallest value under key `'y'` of all dictionaries in the list

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can find the min and max with `min(list_of_dicts, key=lambda d: d['y'])['y']` ...

It's exactly the same as that, but the function `y` does the indexing. It's a bit shorter and [DRYer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) to write it that way.

---

Note that [named lambdas are generally bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381663/4518341), although this case isn't too bad. Best practice is to use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
y = operator.itemgetter('y')
```

---

However, you can do it better by using generator expressions to get the min/max y-values directly, instead of their containing dicts. Then the indexing only happens twice, which makes the function `y` practically pointless.

```
return min(d['y'] for d in list_of_dicts), max(d['y'] for d in list_of_dicts)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm declaring *Abuse of Lambda*. Whenever you see a `lambda` assigned to a variable, you need to ask why give a name to an anonymous function? And when that function lacks a clear name, why make this hard? The function could be rewritten as follows:

```
def get_y(d):
    """Return "y" item from collection `d`"""
    return d['y']

def range_y(list_of_dicts):
    return get_y(min(list_of_dicts, key=get_y)), get_y(max(list_of_dicts, key=get_y))
```

In fact, there is a function in the standard lib that does this, so this may be more expected

```
def range_y(list_of_dicts):
    get_y = operator.itemgetter("y")
    return get_y(min(list_of_dicts, key=get_y)), get_y(max(list_of_dicts, key=get_y))
```

But there is a more straight forward way to write this. `itemgetter` is useful as a key in the min/max searches, but only confuses things once you've selected the dicts.

```
def range_y(list_of_dicts):
    get_y = operator.itemgetter("y")
    return min(list_of_dicts, key=get_y)["y"], max(list_of_dicts, key=get_y)["y"]
```

But since all you care about is the min/max "y", extract those values and work with them from the beginning.

```
def range_y(list_of_dicts):
    y_vals = [d["y"] for d in list_of_dicts]
    return min(y_vals), max(y_vals)
```