# python if/else and try/except combination without redundancy

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, try-except

While playing around with [icecream](https://pypi.org/project/icecream/) I programmed the following lines of code

```py
if __debug__:
    try:
        from icecream import ic
        ic.configureOutput(includeContext=True)
    except ImportError:  # Graceful fallback if IceCream isn't installed.
        ic = lambda *a: None if not a else (a[0] if len(a) == 1 else a)  # noqa
else:
    ic = lambda *a: None if not a else (a[0] if len(a) == 1 else a)  # noqa
```

As you can see I want to assign the (same) lambda expression to `ic` in both cases

1. if not debugging the code or
2. if importing icecream is not working

I was wondering if there is a (maybe pythonic) way to handle that idea without redundancy.

Comment: `ic = lambda ...` `if not __debug__: try: import ... except ImportError: pass`…?

Comment: Thanks @deceze , this " overwriting" the `ic`-definition is a nice idea, but not that pythonic, isn't it?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @deceze I think redefining/overwriting is somehow unclean. But it is just a personal feeling. Indeed your suggestion fulfills my requierment and thus it is good. If no further solution comes up, I'll accept it of course as your answer (if you like to write it that way). Or I'll mention you by self answering.

Comment: @deceze I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993603/4518341) based on your comment, thanks! LMK if there's anything you'd want to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a default, then override it later as needed. I would also add comments to make it clear.

```
def ic(*a):  # May be overridden later
    if not a:
        return None
    return a[0] if len(a) == 1 else a


if __debug__:
    try:
        from icecream import ic  # Override default
    except ImportError:
        pass  # Fallback to default
    else:
        ic.configureOutput(includeContext=True)
```

By the way:

- [Named lambdas are bad practice. Use a `def` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381663/4518341)
- I rewrote the function to avoid a double-conditional-expression for better readability.
- Try to put as little in a "try" clause as necessary, and use `else` to define what should happen if the `try` succeeds.

*<sub>This is based on [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969040/python-if-else-and-try-except-combination-without-redundancy#comment118376395_66969040)</sub>*

Comment: I would add an inline comment directly next to the import that makes it 200% clear that the override is intended. Over time/after refactoring this connection might get lost otherwise.

Comment: I recommend `  # noqa: F811 - no redefinition-error` in the icecream-import-line as this is the corresponding warning (c. f. [flake8](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/F811.html)) @ojdo

Comment: With all that refactoring, this could have been a candidate for codereview.SX :D

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on the pattern suggested by deceze in the comments:

```py
# file my_icecream.py:
def ic(*a):
    """Icecream fallback implementation"""
    if not a:
        return None
    elif len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
    else:
        return a
```

```
# original file
if not __debug__:
    from my_icecream import ic
else:
    try:
        from icecream import ic
        ic.configureOutput(includeContext=True)
    except ImportError:
        from my_icecream import ic
```

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. Just a question: Why do you _invert_ the if clause? Is there a bigger sense ?
And further - in `my_icecream.py` why do you expand the one-liner?

Comment: Both were pure stylistic choices: the breakup of the "oneliner" looks more readable to me, whenever one needs to grasp/modify/adapt it later; but for most purposes, its implementation could/should be as opaque as the `icecream` import hopefully is.

Comment: As for inverting `not __debug__`: I found it cleaner to have the default/production case first, but I could be easily convinced to stay with the order you posted.