# Pandas groupby aggregate list

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'upc':[1,1,1],'store':[1,2,3],'date':['jan','jan','jan'],'pred':[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]],'act':[[4,4,4],[5,5,5],[6,6,6]]})
```

looks like this

```
   upc  store date       pred        act
0    1      1  jan  [1, 1, 1]  [4, 4, 4]
1    1      2  jan  [2, 2, 2]  [5, 5, 5]
2    1      3  jan  [3, 3, 3]  [6, 6, 6]
```

When I do groupby and agg along `store` for `pred` and `act`

```
df.groupby(by = ["upc","date"]).agg({"pred":"sum","act":"sum"})
```

I get all the list concatenated

```
                                pred                          act
upc date                                                          
1   jan   [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]  [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]
```

I want the sum of the list element-wise something like this

```
   upc date       pred           act
0    1  jan  [6, 6, 6]  [15, 15, 15]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with:

```
>>> df.groupby(['upc', 'date'], as_index=False).agg({"pred": lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values.tolist()).sum().tolist(), "act": lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values.tolist()).sum().tolist()})
   upc date       pred           act
0    1  jan  [6, 6, 6]  [15, 15, 15]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use lambda function with convert values to numy array and `sum` per `axis=0`:

```
f = lambda x: np.array(x.tolist()).sum(axis=0).tolist()
df = df.groupby(by = ["upc","date"], as_index=False).agg({"pred":f,"act":f}) 
print (df)
   upc date       pred           act
0    1  jan  [6, 6, 6]  [15, 15, 15]
```

Solution with function:

```
def f(x):
    return np.array(x.tolist()).sum(axis=0).tolist()

df = df.groupby(by = ["upc","date"], as_index=False).agg({"pred":f,"act":f})
```

Comment: using numpy array and the associated methods is always better, but I think a normal python function should have been better instead of named `lambda` . [Is it pythonic: using named lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381556/is-it-pythonic-naming-lambdas)