# How to modify an argument in a lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I've made a function to turn a `MM/DD/YYYY` date into a `DD-MMM-YYYY` date (e.g. `05/03/2023` to `03-MAY-2023`), but in the function I use `date.split('/')` twice and I'd prefer to only use it once.

I know I could use `date = date.split('/')` before the lambda function, I was just wondering if there is a way to do that inline with a lambda function?

```
# Current code
# Given vars
months = ['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN','JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC']
date = "05/03/2023"
# Function
newDate = lambda date : '-'.join([date.split('/')[i] if i != 0 else months[int(date.split('/')[i])-1] for i in [1,0,2]])


# Function I want
newDate = lambda (lambda date : date.split('/'))(date) : '-'.join([date[i] if i != 0 else months[int(date[i])-1] for i in [1,0,2]])
# But this gives a syntax error
```

Comment: lambdas can have as many arguments as you want. But also, why do this as a lambda at all, rather than just writing a normal function and making it do what you need? And of course finally, "why waste time on premature optimization" =)

Comment: [If you're naming a lambda, you shouldn't be using a lambda at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38381556/843953)

Comment: TBH a normal function would probably be more legible, but I've just started learning about lambda functions so I wanted to try one out

Comment: `lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%d-%b-%Y').upper()`

Comment: " I use date.split('/') twice and I'd prefer to only use it once"--you can make use of the Walrus operator to only compute date.split('/') once i.e. `newDate = lambda date : '-'.join([(exp_date:=date.split('/'))[i] if i != 0 else months[int(exp_date[i])-1] for i in [1,0,2]])`

Comment: Pass `date.split('/')` as the parameter to the lambda.  Then process the parts in the lambda.

Comment: @DarrylG that was what I came up with too - it's brittle though, for example if you change it to `...for i in [0,1,2]` it breaks, because `exp_date` is then used before being defined.

Comment: @DarrylG That still calls `split` twice and would error if `i` was zero first, e.g. `[0,1,2]`

Comment: @MarkTolonen how is it calling split twice?

Comment: @DarrylG When i=1 and when i=2.

Comment: A lambda *expression* is another way to define a function that could just as well be defined by a `def` statement: both create instances of `types.FunctionType`. Lambda expressions are a convenience for when you don't necessarily need a function bound to a name in the current scope.

Comment: With only one split and no formal nesting (though the return of 'itemgetter' really is like an inner lambda): `newDate = lambda date : '-'.join(part if j != 1 else months[int(part)-1] for j, part in enumerate(operator.itemgetter(1,0,2)(date.split('/'))))` Note that `j` here isn't the same as the original `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers to your question.

The better answer is that you shouldn't be using a lambda here.  A far cleaner solution would be:

```
def newDate(date):
    parts = date.split('/')
    return '-'.join([parts[i] if i != 0 else months[int(parts[i]) - 1] for i in [1, 0, 2]])
```

This definition of `newDate` can be stuck in the middle of your function (with appropriate indentation), right where you currently define assign `newDate` to a lambda.

If you really insist on using a lambda, you have to use the nested lambda trick.  You create a second lambda that takes `parts` as an argument, and then call that lambda with the value of `parts`:

```
newDate = lambda date: (
                (lambda parts: '-'.join([parts[i] if i != 0 else months[int(parts[i]) - 1] for i in [1, 0, 2]])) (date.split('/')))
```

Your goal is to write readable code.  This isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll just stick to function defs outside of filtering lists and list comprehension from now on. Sometimes I just get so focused on trying to make everything in-line I forget to make it legible

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're asking an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) as there are many better ways to convert the date string in your example.

To answer the core question of whether you can change the value of a variable in a lambda, the answer is yes starting in Python 3.8. See [assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) (aka the "walrus operator").

```py
# simple example
lambda s: n if (n := len(s)) else -1

# terrible (but technically valid) example
lambda date : (d:=date.split('/'),'-'.join(d[i] if i != 0 else months[int(d[i])-1] for i in [1,0,2]))[1]
```

It's likely very rare that changing or assigning a variable within a lambda is a good idea. But you *can* with some syntactic gymnastics.

Comment: Thanks! The cleanest solution I came up while forcing a lambda function was `newDate = lambda date : '-'.join([(date := date.split('/'))[1],months[int(date[0])-1],date[2]])`
but it looks like I should just use a function def for stuff like this from now on