# I need a better way of expanding function conditions than building lambda expressions on top of another

Tags: python, lambda

I have a named lambda expression like this one:

`expr1 = lambda x: x > 3`

For some reasons, along the code I check some flags and might do this:

`expr2 = lambda x: expr1(x) and x % 2 == 0`

So, I am defining a more restrictive lambda expression based on my needs.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381556/is-it-pythonic-naming-lambdas) about naming lambdas that explains how they are not pythonic at all.

What is a better way to define functions that may get more conditions along the code?

Comment: If you want a longer condition, you want a longer condition. Sometimes there's no way around that. For replacing the `lambda` though, you'd just use a normal function defined using `def`,.

Comment: It's not pythonic to use lambdas where regular `def` functions would do. *That's* the problem. Not combining functions, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would use `def` to define a function.

In your specific case, something like the following would work:

```
def greater_than_3(x):
    return x > 3

def even(x):
    return x % 2 == 0

def my_test(x):
    return (greater_than_3(x) and even(x))
```

Then you just need to call `my_test(x)` when required. It returns `True` if `x` satisfies both of the conditions, `False` if not.

You there defined 3 functions instead of only 2 in your code, but as you do not seem to sure about whether or not you will add more conditions later in your code, this allows you to improve readability.