# How to draw a point on an ellipse from general form

Tags: python, draw, point

The following program draws a rotated ellipse from an equation given in general form:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_range = np.linspace(-6, +6)
y_range = np.linspace(-10, +1)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)

A, B, C, D, E, F = 0.25, 0.40, 0.25, 1.50, 2.00, 1.50

f = lambda x, y, A, B, C, D, E, F: A*x**2 + B*x*y +C*y**2 + D*x + E*y + F
equation = f(x, y, A, B, C, D, E, F)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (4, 4), tight_layout = True)

ax.contour(x, y, equation, levels = [0], colors = color)

plt.show()
```

Is there a simple way to draw a point **on** this ellipse,no matter where it is ?

My question comes from the fact that I use `Geogebra` sometimes and, in `Geogebra`, if you draw an ellipse by the input `0.25*x^2 + 0.40*x*y + 0.25*y^2 + 1.5*x + 2*y + 1.5  = 0`, you can easily put a point where you want on the ellipse (and even move it), using the simple instruction `Point on Object`...

I wonder if something similar could be implemented in Python, starting from the small program that I wrote a little above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code draws the ellipse in quite a roundabout way -- it draws a contour of `f == 0` for the values in the 2d array `equation`, which is obtained by calculating the value of `f` at every point on the grid defined by `x` and `y`.

That said, `ax.contour` returns a [`QuadContourSet`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/contour_api.html#matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet) from which you can extract the coordinates being plotted like so:

```
qcs = ax.contour(x, y, equation, levels = [0], colors = color)
pts = qcs.collections[0].get_paths()[0].vertices
```

`pts` is a 2d array of shape `(N, 2)`. Any row of this array is a point on your ellipse. For example:

```
ax.plot(pts[5, 0], pts[5, 1], 'xk')
```

plots the black x below:

[image]

---

If you want to find a point for any arbitrary `x` value, you simply need to obtain the `y` value which solves the equation `f(x, ...) == 0`. [`scipy.optimize.fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) can do this for you. Since `fsolve` takes a function `F` and solves the problem `F(X, args) == 0`, we need to redefine our function so that the *first* argument is the unknown coordinate we're trying to find, and supply the rest as `args` to `fsolve`:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def get_ellipse_point(x, A, B, C, D, E, F, y0):

    def ellipse_func(y, x, A, B, C, D, E, F):
        return A*x**2 + B*x*y +C*y**2 + D*x + E*y + F

    y_pt = fsolve(ellipse_func, y0, (x, A, B, C, D, E, F)
    return (x, y_pt[0])
```

`y0` is your initial guess of the point's `y`. Calling this function, for example, to find points with `x == 0` gives:

```
# Initial guess of y is -10, which will find the point at the bottom of the ellipse
pt_x0_bottom = get_ellipse_point(0, A, B, C, D, E, F, -10)  # (0, -7.16227766016838)

# Initial guess of y is +10, which will find the point at the top of the ellipse
pt_x0_top = get_ellipse_point(0, A, B, C, D, E, F, 10)  # (0, -0.8377223398316207)
```

We can plot these points to make sure we have the correct answer:

```
ax.plot(*pt_x0_bottom, 'ob') # Plot bottom point with blue circle
ax.plot(*pt_x0_top, '^g')    # Plot top point with green triangle
```

[image]

---

Note that I used the `def` keyword to define the function of the ellipse. I could have defined it with a lambda like you did to get the same result, but that is not a good practice (See [Is it pythonic: naming lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38381556/843953))

Comment: Hi, `pho` this is really interesting and I learned a lot of new things about `ax.contour`. It helps me a lot!